# Out of memory error while running gradlew assembleRelease - react-native

Tags: java, out-of-memory, react-native

I am getting this error while making a release build for my react native project:

```
Expiring Daemon because JVM heap space is exhausted
    
> Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForRelease'.
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError (no error message)
```

Done some research and made some changes, which are below:

1. Added  `android:largeHeap="true"` to the application tag in the AndroidManifest.xml
2. Added

   ```
   dexOptions {
       javaMaxHeapSize "4g" 
   }
   ```

   in the android/app/build.gradle file.
3. Added the below code to gradle.properties

   ```
   org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
   org.gradle.daemon=true
   org.gradle.parallel=true
   org.gradle.configureondemand=true
   ```

Still I am not able to get rid of this error. Any permanent way to get rid of this error and how is it caused??

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I needed. You have concluded the fix for this issue.

I guess you have a device that could not have enough RAM to compile your project. Try to use another device with more RAM on it or simply change the amount of RAM allocated in the configuration settings ( instead of 4096 use 8192 or more )

Answer (score 163, accepted):

configuring  gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

Comment: invalidate cache and restart

Comment: Tried it in android studio, but i am using cmdline for taking builds..

Comment: update: its working now after repeated cache invalidating and clearing. :)

Comment: How do I invalidate cache? Am I invalidating it for Android, Npm, something else? Not sure what to look up here

Comment: Adding the parallel bit caused my build to fail in other weird and wonderful ways - but removing the last three lines and just keeping the first line worked for me.

Comment: in my RN project android/gradle.properties, just uncommented line 13

> org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

Comment: We don't need this `org.gradle.daemon=true` anymore, since it is true by default.
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html

Comment: "Make sure gradle.properties does not include org.gradle.configureondemand=true as that will make the release build skip bundling JS and assets into the app binary." https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android#generating-the-release-aab

Answer (score 10):

Although the given answer did not work for me, it did lead me to the correct path. Sometimes the build would go through but then again after some time this error would resurface, so to resolve it once and for all:

First comment `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m` inside your project's gradle properties.

Add the following in your app/build.gradle:

```
android {

  dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
  }

}
```

Now edit your global gradle.properties for mac it'll be inside Home/YOUR_USERNAME/.gradle/
Note that .gradle is a hidden folder.

If the file is not there simply create it and add

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: This is what worked for me

Comment: Warning dexOptions is obsolete and it will be removed in version 8.0 of the Android Gradle plugin

Answer (score 4):

this worked for me!

uncommenting this line in android/gradle.properties

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

credit @Alex Aymkin

Comment: It worked for me, I uncommented this line in android/gradle.properties.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Adding this code in the android/gradle.properties worked for me!

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```